# How can I push constantly streaming data (which I have converted to color) into successive divs in my index.html using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, websocket

I am trying to turn the computer screen into a grid and then push data (in the form of color) into each square of the grid. When one square is full I want to fill the next one. I have the data streaming in using Socket.io. I'd appreciate some suggestions on how to adjust the Javascript below to enable this?

My html is a series of rows that look like this:

```
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

My client-side javascript:

```
var socket = io()

socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('client is connected');
})

socket.on('color', function (data) {
  const { rgb } = data
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]].join(',') + ')';

});
```

Comment: Your problem is that backround is changing but individual div color is not changing?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I worked out how to change the background fine, but not sure how to approach using divs.

Comment: You must assign divs ids and then select them through jQuery selectors. Do you have any idea about jQuery selectors and how to use them. It would be quite helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll have a go at that.

Comment: Yout are welcome. You can ping me if you stuck somewhere  ...

Comment: Hi Rai, the code all looks good, but when I start the server the app just sits idle in the browser. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: @RaiAmmadKhan forgot to add you to my comment above. I have posted my new code below. Do I need to trigger the event as you have done in your demo?

Comment: Have you verified your socket connection.  Like:
socket.on('connect', function () { conole.log("Its working")
})

Comment: If your javascript file is included in the HTML page.  You dont need to trigger it. I am suggesting you to use console.log(): to verify your function is being called or not

Comment: In firefox browser press F12 to see console screen. And see if your msg appears on the screen or not

Comment: @RaiAmmadKhan I have tried the console.log and it appears the socket connection is not working?

Comment: Why do you need socket connection? do you want to send data to another server or something like this.

Comment: @RaiAmmadKhan I'm streaming data from twitter so I need the connection open for that. The server is constantly pushing that data to client.

Comment: OK. Whats your status now? Socket Connection working?

Comment: And I heard about earthquake in New Zealand. Are you fine?

Comment: @RaiAmmadKhan thanks for your concern. We were fine in the earthquake, but it has obviously affected our lives with some buildings now unsafe and being demolished. It was quite a shake, and we're thankful it was during the night and not at a busy time in the city.

Socket connection is still not working unfortunately. It is bound to be something simple, but I'm not seeing it. The code is on github if you'd like to have a look: https://github.com/martybutts/mood-ring-pixilation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the new code using socket.io:

```
var socket = io()
const div = document.querySelector(".row>div"); 

socket.on('connect', function () {
})

socket.on('color', function (data) {

  const { rgb } = data

  div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]].join(',') + ')';
  if (div.nextElementSibling) {
   div = div.nextElementSibling;
  }
  else {
   div = div.parentElement.children[0];
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select your div with [`.querySelector(query)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and then move to the next one with [`.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling). When you are at the last one you need to select the first child of the parent with `parentElement.children[0]`.

Here is an example with pure WebSockets, but you should be able to make it work with Socket.io:

```js
var div = document.querySelector(".row>div"); // select the first div
var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org/");
websocket.onmessage = function(evt) {
  var rgb = JSON.parse(evt.data);
  // change the color of the div
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + [rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]].join(',') + ')';
  if (div.nextElementSibling) // if a div is not last, move to the next one
    div = div.nextElementSibling;
  else // if the div is last move to the first one
    div = div.parentElement.children[0];
};

// code just to make the demo work and trigger the onmessage event
websocket.onopen = function(evt) {
n = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify([255*((n>>2)&1), 255*((n>>1)&1), 255*(n&1)]));
    n++;
  }, 100);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*height: 50px;*/
  width: 100%;
}

.row > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```